# How do I fix the Type Error: a float is required?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, floating

It says that a float is required. Can anyone help me fix this code:

```
from time import sleep
print("Welcome to this game of random.") ; sleep(1.0)
print("Type in your name:") ; sleep(0.5)
playerName = raw_input()
print("Welcome " + playerName + " Type how fast do you want the text to go in this format: 1.0") ; sleep(1.0)
speed = raw_input()
print("You choosed: " + speed) ; sleep(speed)
```

Is there an error that needs to be fixed?

Comment: Can you post the error traceback

Comment: @GamersHub, I agree with JBernardo, you should be learning Python 3.

Comment: @JBernardo I will soon once I finish with this project of mine.

Answer (score 0):

`speed` is a string and you are doing `sleep(speed)`

`sleep` requires a `float` or `int` so you need to do a `sleep(float(speed))`. This assumes the input will be a number and therefore won't fail when converting to a `float`

You should be validating the input of speed to ensure it is a proper format using `try/except`

Answer (score 0):

Because `sleep` takes a number (`int` or `float`) as parameter, you need to cast the value returned by `raw_input` when it is assigned to `speed`. I think you are using Python 2, so `raw_input` which equivalent in Python 3 is `input`, will return a string:

```py
from time import sleep
print("Welcome to this game of random.") ; sleep(1.0)
print("Type in your name:") ; sleep(0.5)
playerName = raw_input()
print("Welcome " + playerName + " Type how fast do you want the text to go in this format: 1.0") ; sleep(1.0)
## LOOK AT THE FOLLOWING LINE
speed = float(raw_input())
print("You choosed: " + str(speed)) ; sleep(speed)
```

Also, do not forget to convert `speed` to `str` since you cannot concatenate a `str` and `float`.